# Parsing weird date format

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have this weird date format that I have to parse.

2015-12-18T03:36:06.000+0000

I am currently mapping a regex to date formats so I can parse different dates. However, this format got me confused. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently reading this question but i need help in understand what is your problem. Any help appreciated. Are you looking for a regular expression for the date ? or you want to know how you can parse this ?

Comment: Joda time has formatting options that can handle this.

Comment: @StackFlowed I am trying to parse the date format however I cannot figure out the regex or the format it is in for SimpleDateFormat

Comment: It's not weird, its [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: [Converting ISO-8601 compliant string to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date).

Comment: It not just not weird, it also been asked before, several times if I recall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse a `String` into a `Date` in Java, you use a `DateFormat` object, and specify the format the date is in. There is no need to use a Regex, the Java library has a way to do this for you.

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
final Date d = df.parse("2015-12-18T03:36:06.000+0000");  // From your code above
System.out.println(d);
```

See the [JavaDoc for SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more explanation as to what the symbols mean. This is actually a common format for dates called ISO 8601, I just took the pattern right from the documentation.

Watch out! These DateFormat objects are not threadsafe.

Comment: A better solution probably be to use the new date/time API

Comment: [An answer by Adam](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27479533/642706) using the new date/time API (java.time) can be found on [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2201925/642706) of which this question is a duplicate.